# Cron is still processing the jobs in the background even after I stopped the cron from running

Tags: cron

Can anyone please tell me about the following behaviour? I want to stop the batch tasks to be run in the background, so I stopped the cron using this command

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/cron stop
```

And after this I can see the message

```
[ ok ] Stopping cron (via systemctl): cron.service.
```

I created one batch task to check whether this is working or not, but cron is still running every minute and processing the tasks.

Please tell me how do I stop cron to not process any task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put a comment(#) before the cronjob and reload the cron service.

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and run

```
sudo service cron stop
```

And if it is not stopping the cron, you can backup the crontab and remove it's entry.

```
crontab -l > cron_backup.txt

crontab -r
```

Note that it will remove all crontab entries from machine. If you don't want to remove it and just want to disable it, adding a `#` in front of crontab entries would also do the job.

To restore the crontab

```
crontab cron_backup.txt
```

**OR**

You may use the `pkill` command to kill the cronjob by providing the process id.

You will get the process id from the following command.

```
ps -e | grep cron
```

Use the process id in the following command.

```
pkill <process id>
```